# DNS Resolution = Do not know where DNS Records come from

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, debian

I use debian:

```
 /etc/hostname => static  (meaning my hostname is called static)
```

and

```
/etc/hosts     => 127.0.0.1       localhost
```

and now

`traceroute static  ==> Traceroute resolves to (xx.xx.xx.30)` a very strange and unknown/wrong host.

and

`dig static`   => resloves to the ROOT-Namesevers ...

My Question:

1. Most likely I need to define in /etc/hosts my hostname to ip adress mapping. that is the cause of the problem. (something like yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy static =>myip to hostname mapping)
2. But(!!!) I want to understand where traceroute gets this weired IP-Adress. I would be very thankfull if someone can explain how this IP Adress is retrievend and where does it come from

Thank you very much!!! Markus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the result when you enter "nslookup static"? That should show you which nameserver is beint used and which record that nameserver has for "static"

Comment: hello Jannemans, Thanks very much for your help! You fixed it;-) with nslookup I realized that (I have two virutal machines, one is working, the other one had this problem described) had different Name-Servers. And that got me to /etc/reslov.conf where the machine that was not working had this strange IP Adress as "search IP Adress"... Althrough the nameserveras are diffrent, the problem was the wrong "search..." statement... When I commented out that line I got an NXDOMAIN. Now everything is working. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Glad to have nudged you in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning NXDOMAIN (this host doesn't exist), your ISP's DNS server is returning the IP of their search page.  Try popping open a web browser and going to http://static; my guess is that you'll hit a page saying "we couldn't find 'static' -- did you mean *something else*?" along with a bunch of ads.

That said, add:

> 127.0.0.1 static

to your /etc/hosts file, and you should be good to go.